# Problem with exports pgf/tikz graphic

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am encountering an error when trying to export this graphic.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-3.,-3.) rectangle (3.,3.);
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.0:3.0] plot(\x,{(9.0-(\x)^(3.0))^(1/(3.0))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `domain=-2.0:2.0`.

Comment: In support of @ferahfeza let me add that, if you go all the way to 3, you will ask pgf to compute `(<something negative>)^(1/3)`, which is of course nothing but `exp((1/3)*ln(<something negative>))`, which is not a well-defined real number, i.e. nothing you can plot. @ferahfeza suggest to keep the argument of the logarithm positive.